# Track time for loading screen: Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I've added a loading component in my Angular 2 application where I show the loading animation on every async call to a webapi. I want to add another feature to that loading component. i.e., if loading is taking more than 5 seconds then I want to show a helper message on top of the loading animation. So any suggestions how can I 'track' the time of the loading animation? I'm guessing there should be a Javascript function, but can't find anything yet that can make this work.

Comment: Did you mean how long the initial loading/bootstrapping of the angular app and the DOM takes, or just a single component? Show some of the code that you tried

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a hurry, something like this works for me.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';

@Component({
  selector: 'your-selector',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1 *ngIf="firstLoader">First Loading...</h1>
      <h1 *ngIf="secondLoader">Second Loading..</h1>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

  firstLoader: boolean = true;
  secondLoader: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private _http: Http
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.secondLoader = true;
    }, 1000); // your second loader interval
    this._http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .delay(2000) // add network throttling
      .subscribe(res => {
      // console.log(res);
      this.firstLoader = false;
      this.secondLoader = false;
    })
  }
}
```